# hash scrolling navigation with sticky header, offset not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, contentoffset

I have a website with a stick to top header, when scrolling, half of my header disappear and the menu stick to top.
the navigation uses hash, by clicking on a link of my menu, the page scrolls to the linked #.
I've added a jscript to calcul the height of my stickyheader to add this height to my #link so my target is displayed right under my menu.
it works perfectly on Chrome & safari, but in Firefox, there's a problem, the height is not added, so my title is displayed under the menu. 
And when clicking to "back to top", the position is not correct, there's an offset... only on firefox also.

I don't know if you understand what I mean, so here is a jsfiddle to see it in action :

http://jsfiddle.net/rHmAA/3/

here is my js :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href^="#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
            $target = $(target);

        var offset;
        if($('#stickyheader').css('position') == 'relative'){
            offset = $('#stickyheader').outerHeight(true)*2;
        }else{
            offset = $('#stickyheader').outerHeight(true);
        }
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - offset
            //--OFFSET--//
        }, 1500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});

$(function () {
    // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#stickyheader').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() === stickyHeaderTop+1) {
            $('#stickyheader').hide();
            console.log('p');
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop) {
            $('#stickyheader').fadeIn(500).css('position','fixed');
            $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'block');
            var mT = $('#stickyheader').css('height');
            $('#stickyheader').next('.post').css('marginTop', mT);
        }else{
            $('#stickyheader').css({
                position: 'relative',
            });
            $('#stickyheader').next('.post').css('marginTop', '0');
        }
    });
});
```

can anybody help me with this ? I don't know what I am doing wrong,

thanks a lot for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for the scroll animate

```
 $('html, body').animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - offset
       //--OFFSET--//
 }, 1500);
```

Comment: thanks @James, it works perfectly, can you please explain me what I was doing wrong ? thanks

Comment: to be frank i couldn't figure out what is wrong. I faced the same issue and this solved my problem. So i thought i will post this and it might help you.